# Toner Transfer + GBC Creative 9 Laminator: GBC Mod Question

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, toner-transfer

After receiving a ton of feedback from [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/best-one-off-diy-pcb-creation-technique), I decided to give the old toner method a try once again. I grabbed a GBC Creative 9 laminator off of [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MBLW90) for $23 and am now looking to modify it to produce more heat for the transfer.

I ran across [UltraKeet Australia](http://ultrakeet.com.au/index.php?id=article&name=fritzHack) where PodeCoet modified a similar GBC laminator for the same purpose. I got the laminator in the other day and quickly took it apart only to realize that my model was slightly different. Unlike his model, I only have one thermal switch in my unit.

Here is a picture of the thermal switch and thermal fuse that comes with the Creative 9 laminator.

[image: Thermal Switch (left) and Thermal Fuse (right)]

One thing that I noticed on PodeCoet's laminator, he has a switch on the front of his unit which allows 3mm and 5mm items to be inserted. He also labeled the two thermal switches noting that one was for 3mm and one for 5mm. This may explain the missing component on my system.

I am wondering if and how I can safely modify my unit to produce more heat for the Toner Transfer method. Also, if anyone can point me in the direction of a component that will put out around 200-220 celcius, I would be much appreciated as I have not found anything cheaper than $35 (on Mouser).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a GBC Creative 9 laminator with great results and I performed the exact modification you're trying to make! (except I followed these instructions: http://frikkieg.blogspot.com/2009/08/us-pcb-laminator.html)

I just went ahead and swapped out the parts as the tutorial said, and it's worked great. You can see [my pcb making method and results here](http://www.robotenthusiasts.com/tutorials/?p=46).